# Android compose text overflow weight is not work

Tags: android, text, layout, android-jetpack-compose

RI am developing an Android app using jetpack compose.

Here is a very basic UI component:

[image]

I want to add a button on the right side.

But if the name is very long, the button is gone.

My code is here:

```kotlin
Row(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
) {
    Row(
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = rememberImagePainter(data = profileImg),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(56.dp)
                .clip(CircleShape)
        )

        Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1F) // I set the weight in here but it doesn't work.
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "very very very very very very very long name",
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                maxLines = 1,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
            )
            Text(
                text = "3 minutes ago",
            )
        }
    }

    Row {
        Button()
        Button()
    }
}
```

How can I show the right button correctly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Text layout priority in Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68320333/text-layout-priority-in-jetpack-compose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually provide that weight to `Row` containing your `Text` & make sure you don't cover the entire width. e.g don't do just `1f`.

You can do something like this; (This is done with `compose_version = '1.0.1'`)

```
@Composable
fun Item() {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            modifier = Modifier.weight(0.7f)
        ) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background),
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(56.dp)
                    .clip(CircleShape)
            )

            Column(
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "very very very very very very very long name",
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    maxLines = 1,
                    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                )
                Text(
                    text = "3 minutes ago",
                )
            }
        }

        Button(
            onClick = {}, modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentWidth()
                .weight(0.3f)
        ) {
            Text(text = "Button")
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image: compose weight]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working code (I've removed useless Row, it's simpler that way)

```
@Composable
fun Test() {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(5.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = rememberImagePainter(data = profileImg),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(56.dp)
                .clip(CircleShape)
        )

        Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f) // I set the weight in here but it doesn't work.
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "very very very very very very very long name",
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                maxLines = 1,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
            )
            Text(
                text = "3 minutes ago",
            )
        }

        Button(onClick = { }) {
            Text(text = "Btn1")
        }
        Button(onClick = { }) {
            Text(text = "Btn2")
        }
    }
}
```

[image: rox]

Answer (score 0):

Even though the other question are right I am going to explain your mistake, to better understand what is going on.

So you need:
A `Row()` which will contain those 3:

1. `Image`
2. `Column`
3. and a `Row` with the two buttons

[image]

In other words something like:

```
Row() {
   Image()
   Column(weight:1f)
   Row()
}
```

Your mistake is that you created a `Row` with two other `Rows` without weights and you get this weird output.

So if you simply delete your outer `Row` and move your `Row of buttons` like so it will work:

[image]